# Php radio button con if que no escoge

Tags: php, if, radiobutton

tengo un formulario creado en una pagina donde hay dos radio button para el sexo, en la siguiente trato de hacer un if para saber si en la bd guardo M o F, pero es como si se quedara en el valor que traía antes de hacer el update

```
while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){     
            echo "<div align='center'>";    
            echo "<form action='cliente_actualizar_datos.php' method='get'>";

            echo "<label for='identificacion'>Identificación </label> &nbsp;";      
            echo "<input type='text' name='identificacion' value='". $fila['identificacion'] . "'><br>";

            echo "<label for='nombre'>Nombre </label> &nbsp;";      
            echo "<input type='text' name='nombre' value='". $fila['nombre'] . "'><br>";

            echo "<label for='direccion'>Dirección </label> &nbsp;";        
            echo "<input type='text' name='direccion' value='". $fila['direccion'] . "'><br>";

            echo "<label for='telefono'>Teléfono </label> &nbsp;";      
            echo "<input type='text' name='telefono' value='". $fila['telefono'] . "'><br>";

            echo "<label for='correo'>Correo </label> &nbsp;";  
            echo "<input type='text' name='correo' value='". $fila['correo'] . "'><br>";

            /*echo "<label for='sexo'>Sexo </label> &nbsp;";    
            echo "<input type='text' name='sexo' value='". $fila['sexo'] . "'><br>"; */

            echo "<label id='label1' name='sexoLabel'>Sexo </label> &nbsp"; 
            if($fila['sexo'] == 'M'){
                echo "<input type='radio' name='sexo' value='M' class='textoBlanco' checked> Masculino &nbsp";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='sexo' value='F' class='textoBlanco'> Femenino<br><br>";
            }else{
                echo "<input type='radio' name='sexo' value='M' class='textoBlanco' > Masculino &nbsp";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='sexo' value='F' class='textoBlanco' checked> Femenino<br><br>";
            }                               

            echo "<label for='estado_civil'>Estado Civil </label> &nbsp;";  
            echo "<input type='text' name='estado_civil' value='". $fila['estado_civil'] . "'><br>";

            echo "<div class='button'>";
            echo "<button type='submit' name='submit' value='actualizar'>Actualizar</button>";  
             //<button type="submit" name="submit">Guardar</button>     
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</form>"; 
            echo "</div>";
```

Y el que trabaja con los datos:

```
$identificacion=$_GET["identificacion"];
    $nombre=$_GET["nombre"];
    $direccion=$_GET["direccion"];
    $telefono=$_GET["telefono"];
    $correo=$_GET["correo"];
    //$sexo=$_GET["sexo"];
    $Masculino = (isset($_GET["Masculino"]))?true:false;                                
        if($Masculino == true){
            $sexo = "M";
        } 
        else{
            $sexo = "F";
        }   
    $estado_civil=$_GET["estado_civil"];        

    $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra,$db_nombre);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Fallo al conectar con la base de datos";
        exit();
    }

    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die("No se encuentra la base de datos");
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");

    $consulta="UPDATE tbl_clientes SET nombre='$nombre', 
    direccion='$direccion', 
    telefono='$telefono', 
    correo='$correo', 
    sexo='$sexo', 
    estado_civil='$estado_civil'
    WHERE identificacion='$identificacion'";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo esto es innecesario:

```
$Masculino = (isset($_GET["Masculino"]))?true:false;                                
        if($Masculino == true){
            $sexo = "M";
        } 
        else{
            $sexo = "F";
        }
```

Primeramente en el `GET` no habrá ningún valor con la clave `Masculino`, dado que lo que hace de clave al enviar el formulario es el valor de la etiqueta `name` de cada elemento dentro del formulario.

Si tú usas este condicional:

```
    if($fila['sexo'] == 'M'){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='sexo' value='M' class='textoBlanco' checked> Masculino &nbsp";
        echo "<input type='radio' name='sexo' value='F' class='textoBlanco'> Femenino<br><br>";
    }else{
        echo "<input type='radio' name='sexo' value='M' class='textoBlanco' > Masculino &nbsp";
        echo "<input type='radio' name='sexo' value='F' class='textoBlanco' checked> Femenino<br><br>";
    }
```

Puedes determinar el valor chequeado simplemente así:

```
$sexo=(empty($_GET["sexo"])) ? "" : $_GET["sexo"];
```

Como puedes ver, en el `GET` se usa `sexo`, que como está identificado el checkbox por su etiqueta `name`. El operador ternario evalúa con `empty` no sólo si está seteada, sino también si no es vacía. Si lo es, le asigna `""` a `$sexo` y si no, recoge el valor recogido en la clave `sexo` del `GET`.

También, esta línea sobra:

<s>`mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die("No se encuentra la base de datos");`</s>

Pues ya seleccionaste la base de datos aquí:

```
$conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra,$db_nombre);
```

Y también, debes ejecutar finalmente la consulta:

```
if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)) {
    printf("Se actualizaron %d filas.\n", mysqli_num_rows($resultado));

    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
}
```

---

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**
>
> Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL. Una vez
>   resuelto este problema, considera usar consultas preparadas para dar
>   seguridad al código.

---

**Otras observaciones**

La forma de utilizar tus checkboxes es precaria en el sentido de que no se establece ningún control **para evitar por ejemplo que se seleccionen ambos**. Si eso ocurriera vas a tener problemas del lado del servidor. En este caso, del lado del cliente tú deberías tener un control (vía Javascript) que permita seleccionar sólo un checkbox a la vez. Ese control podría además usar el valor de `$fila['sexo']` para decidir qué valor debería ser chequeado.

Es más, si es un valor que no va a cambiar, puedes ponerlo como `disabled`, así evitas sorpresas.

Comment: Gracias Cedano  f